# How do you query for all packages defined by an external repostiory in Bazel

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

For instance take "com_google_protobuf" defined by https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf.

It should show some list like

:timestamp

:duration

.

.

.

You can get a list of these if a package in your own repository already depends on a rule from an external package.

With

```
bazel query 'deps(//path/to/rule)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query using the workspace name, eg:

```
bazel query --output label '@com_google_protobuf//...'
```

Which would list all the labels in the external repository named `com_google_protobuf`.

If you explicitly want packages, then use `--output package`

Comment: GREAT! Thank you

Comment: No worries, you can mark this as the accepted answer if it solved your question.